# How do i access an outlook account inbox using c#?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, imap, inbox

How do i access an outlook account inbox using c#? I've tried using the outlook object model and imap but it only displays the outlook account logged into my machine. I try logging into a different account with  its username and password but it still logs into my local machine account. I read that logging out and closing outlook should fix this problem but it didn't change the results

Here is the code

```
   using System;
   using System.Reflection;

   using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
       public class Class1
       {
           public static int Main(string[] args)
           {
               try
               {

                   Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

                   // Get the MAPI namespace.
                   Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");             
                   oNS.Logon("email address placeholder", "password placeholder", false, true);

                   //Get the Inbox folder.
                   Outlook.MAPIFolder oInbox = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                   String user = oNS.CurrentUser.EntryID;

                   //Get the Items collection in the Inbox folder.
                   Outlook.Items oItems = oInbox.Items;

                   Console.WriteLine(oItems.Count);               
                   Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetFirst();

                   Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Subject);
                   Console.WriteLine(oMsg.SenderName);
                   Console.WriteLine(oMsg.ReceivedTime);
                   Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Body);

                   int AttachCnt = oMsg.Attachments.Count;
                   Console.WriteLine("Attachments: " + AttachCnt.ToString());

                   if (AttachCnt > 0) 
                   {
                   for (int i = 1; i <= AttachCnt; i++) 
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + "-" + oMsg.Attachments[i].DisplayName);
                   }

            for (int i = 0; i < oItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (oItems.GetNext() is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oItems.GetNext();
                    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Subject);
                    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.SenderName);
                    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.ReceivedTime);
                    Console.WriteLine(oMsg.Body);
                    AttachCnt = oMsg.Attachments.Count;
                    if (AttachCnt > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= AttachCnt; j++)
                            Console.WriteLine(j.ToString() + "-" + oMsg.Attachments[j].DisplayName);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Attachments: " + AttachCnt.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("CURRENT EMAIL # IS: " + i);
                }
               else
                {
                    oItems.GetNext();
                    Console.WriteLine("NOT AN EMAIL");
                    Console.WriteLine("CURRENT EMAIL # IS: " + i);
                }


            }

            oNS.Logoff();

            oMsg = null;
            oItems = null;
            oInbox = null;
            oNS = null;
            oApp = null;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught: ", e);


        }

        return 0;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show a minimal version of the code you tried and the result of that code.

Comment: Was that account added to Outlook?

Comment: Yes I tried adding the different account to Outlook but it still went to my main email address. I'm using the .Logon function and I'm not completely sure if I have the right format down for the parameters for the username. Is it the email address itself or something else? Also, how exactly does the code interact with the Outlook app to determine who is the user? Would i need to do anything on Outlook's end to allow access into the inbox?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this code:

```
public List<Outlook.MailItem> GetMails()
{
  Microsoft,Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = OutLookName.Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
  nameSpace.Logon("","",System.Reflection.Missing.Value,System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  List<Outlook.MailItem> eMails = new List<Outlook.MailItem>();

  foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem in inboxFolder.Items)
  {
    if(mailItem.UnRead)
      eMails.Add(mailItem);
  }
return eMails;
}
```

Comment: I have access to two different email accounts with the same credentials. I am able to access one but how do I get access to the second mailbox?

Comment: The following code worked for me. Outlook.MAPIFolder theInbox = oNS.Folders["Mailbox - Name Here"].Folders["Inbox"];